# Import data from Microsoft Works database into SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, import

How can data be imported from a Microsoft Works database (*.wdb file) into a SqlServer2005 database.

Would SSIS be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but you could export the wdb to csv. Here's link explaining how to export uisng either Microsoft Works or just the .wdb file: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/10/convert-microsoft-works-database-wdb-to-csv-or-excel-without-works-installed/
SQL server can easily import csv.